# Open a Browser Window with Javascript on Xamarin.Forms

Tags: javascript, xamarin, xamarin.forms, uno-platform

I have a Xamarin.Forms app. It includes a button like this:

```
 <Button x:Name="Buy_Button" Text="Satın Al" FontAttributes="Bold" TextColor="#e2e2e2" BackgroundColor="#2A52BE" FontFamily="Segoe UI" Grid.Column="2" Grid.ColumnSpan="1" Grid.RowSpan="1"  CornerRadius="5"  VerticalOptions="Start" HorizontalOptions="Center" FontSize="15.667" Grid.Row="0" Margin="0,10,10,0"  Clicked="Buy_Button_ClickedAsync" CommandParameter="{Binding  Buy_URL}" />
```

I'm sending a URL link to click event for opening specific web page. Code is:

```
  private async void Buy_Button_ClickedAsync(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Button btn = (Button)sender; // Coming button from click event handler.
        var buylink = btn.CommandParameter.ToString(); // Get the CommandParameter.
                                                       //  await DisplayAlert("Satın alma linki", buylink, "Anladım"); // Show the link.
        try // Uwp & iOS & Android
        {
            await Browser.OpenAsync(new Uri(buylink), BrowserLaunchMode.SystemPreferred); // Open url in-app browser for iOS & Android- native in UWP
        }
        catch (NotImplementedInReferenceAssemblyException ex) //Wasm falls here because lack of Xamarin.Essentials.
        {
            // await DisplayAlert("Hata", ex.Message, "Anladım"); // Show the info about exception.

            // Jint - nt is a Javascript interpreter for .NET which provides full ECMA 5.1 compliance and can run on any .NET platform. 
            //Because it doesn't generate any .NET bytecode nor use the DLR it runs relatively small scripts faster. 
            //https://github.com/sebastienros/jint

            var engine = new Engine();
            engine.SetValue("log", new Action<object>(Console.WriteLine));

            engine.Execute(@"function openurl() { log('" + buylink + "'); }; openurl(); ");
        }
    }
```

In UWP, Xamarin.iOS and Xamarin. Android this code is running via Xamarin.Esssentials:

```
 await Browser.OpenAsync(new Uri(buylink), BrowserLaunchMode.SystemPreferred); // Open url in-app browser for iOS & Android- native in UWP
```

However, my Xamarin.Forms app projected to WebAssembly code with Uno Platform, so this code block not running. As a result. I install [Jint](https://github.com/sebastienros/jint) to Xamarin.Forms app. This catch block prints the link to Browser console, but no window.open function track in API reference:

```
 catch (NotImplementedInReferenceAssemblyException ex) //Wasm falls here because lack of Xamarin.Essentials.
            {
                // await DisplayAlert("Hata", ex.Message, "Anladım"); // Show the info about exception.

                       // Jint - nt is a Javascript interpreter for .NET which provides full ECMA 5.1 compliance and can run on any .NET platform. 
                //Because it doesn't generate any .NET bytecode nor use the DLR it runs relatively small scripts faster. 
                //https://github.com/sebastienros/jint

                var engine = new Engine();
                engine.SetValue("log", new Action<object>(Console.WriteLine));

                engine.Execute(@"function openurl() { log('" + buylink + "'); }; openurl(); ");
            }
        }
```

How can I open WebBrowser page on WASM via Javascript form Xamarin.Forms C# code? Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

2 things:

## 1. Use the browser!

On Wasm, you're running in a *webassembly* environment, which is running in a ***javascript*** virtual machine (that's not totally accurate, but close enough for my point). That means you can directly invoke the javascript of the running environment (browser).

#### Making a call to *native* javascript...

```cs
WebAssemblyRuntime
    .InvokeJS("(function(){location.href=\"https://www.wikipedia.com/\";})();");
```

> In your case, since you want to **open a browser window**, it's required to use this approach, because Jint can't access anything from the browser itself.

## 2. You can still call Jint anyway (but not to open a new window)

If you still want to call code using Jint (because you can!!), you need to exclude the `Jint.dll` assembly from the linking process. Probably because it's using reflection to operate. **Again, it won't work to open a window as you're asking**, but if you need to call *Jint* for any other reason, it will work as on other platforms!

#### Add this to your `LinkerConfig.xml` (in the Wasm project):

```xml
  <assembly fullname="Jint" />
```

## Also... You gave me an idea and I did something cool with Jint...

I put the entire solution there: https://github.com/carldebilly/TestJint

It works, even on Wasm:
[image]

Interesting code:
https://github.com/carldebilly/TestJint/blob/master/TestJint/TestJint.Shared/MainPage.xaml.cs#L18-L40

```cs
        private void BtnClick(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            void Log(object o)
            {
                output.Text = o?.ToString() ?? "<null>";
            }

            var engine = new Engine()
                    .SetValue("log", new Action<object>(Log));

            engine.Execute(@"
      function hello() { 
        log('Hello World ' + new Date());
      };

      hello();
    ");

#if __WASM__
            output2.Text =
                WebAssemblyRuntime.InvokeJS("(function(){return 'Hello World ' + new Date();})();");
#else
            output2.Text = "Not supported on this platform.";
#endif
        }
```

## Final Note

On *UWP/WinUI XAML*, you can directly put a `<Hyperlink />` in your XAML. I'm not familiar enough with Xamarin Forms to know if there's an equivalent.

Comment: Hi @Carl e Billy. Thanks for answer. I can do it via Xamarin. Forms label for UWP/WinUI XAML (Xamarin.Forms have a <Hyperlink /> equivalent inside Label class). I will try your suggestions and let you learn the outputs.

Comment: Thanks @Carl de Billy,

How can use it on Xamarin. Forms app ?  **WebAssemblyRuntime.InvokeJS** available in Uno.UI class. If I install NuGet package of it to Forms project, VS cannot build and deploy UWP app side because of class ambiguity.

Answer (score 1):

I am using Device.OpenUri and it works in WASM with Xamarin.Forms

```
Device.OpenUri(new Uri("https://www.bing.com"));
```

Comment: Thanks. I will try again :)